# youtube gdata api for rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was searching for a ruby ( 1.9 ) on rails 3 gdata api and didn't seem to find any . Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gem has migrated to a newer version :

https://github.com/kylejginavan/youtube_it

The current version is compatible with Rails 3 / 3.1 as well as Ruby 1.9.x

Answer (score 4):

What about this one?
https://github.com/tmm1/youtube-g

Seems like it supports 1.9 since it has a 1.9 fix in the last commit message.
Also its a ruby wrapper and doesn't depent on rails.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thats odd because this gem does not use rails at all and can also be used outside the rails framework.
Do you get a specific error?

Comment: I did some testing and it works for me in rails 3. I think you might forgot to require the lib manually because rails doesn't do this for you. What i done is: 1) add gem 'youtube-g' to Gemfile 2) bundle install 3) rails c 4) $ require 'youtube_g' after this it worked and i could execute the examples on their github home.

Comment: all is ok but when i type in the rails console require 'youtube_g' i get errors : " SyntaxError: /home/badescuga/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/youtube-g-0.5.0/lib/youtube_g/request/user_search.rb:18: Invalid break
" and this is just the first row

Comment: I see that this bug is fixed in the latest commit: https://github.com/tmm1/youtube-g/commit/c26bf0f45ed6b6cfb941fca4af3835de84cad5e8 i think he didn't do a push to the gem. I have sent an email to the author and will post any updates i get from him.